# Electron: loading an external script and passing it into a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, external, require

I am building an Atom Electron app. Right now I have this in the preload.js of one of my webviews:

```
var { requireTaskPool } = require('electron-remote');
var work = '';
var _ = require('lodash');

work = requireTaskPool(require.resolve('./local/path/to/js/file.js'));


function scriptRun() {
  console.log('Preload: Script Started');
  // `work` will get executed concurrently in separate background processes
  // and resolve with a promise
  _.times(1, () => {
    work(currentTab).then(result => {
      console.log(`Script stopped. Total time running was ${result} ms`);
    });
  });
}
module.exports = scriptRun;
scriptRun();
```

It gets a **local** script and then executes it in a background process.

I want to do the same exact thing, except I want to retrieve the script from an external source like so

```
work = requireTaskPool(require.resolve('https://ex.com/path/to/js/file.js'));
```

When I do this, I get errors like:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'https://ex.com/path/to/js/file.js'
```

How can I load external scripts? And then use the loaded scripts with my `work` function. My feeling is that require only works with local files. If AJAX is the answer, can I see an example of how to get a script, then pass it into my `work` without executing it prior?

Comment: Have you got any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to load a remote js file and execute the function defined in it, hopefully it will provide you enough to start with...

my remote dummy.js, available online somewhere:

```
const dummy = () => console.log('dummy works');
```

my download.js:

```
const vm = require("vm");
const rp = require('request-promise');

module.exports = {
    downloadModule: async () => {
        try {
            let body = await rp('http://somewhere.online/dummy.js');
            let script = vm.createScript(body);
            script.runInThisContext();

            // this is the actual dummy method loaded from remote dummy.js
            // now available in this context:
            return dummy;

        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

You need to add the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) package.

Then in my main.js I use it like this:

```
const {downloadModule} = require('./download');

downloadModule().then((dummy) => {
    if (dummy) dummy();
    else console.log('no dummy');
});
```

When I run it, this is what I get:

```
$ electron .

 dummy works
```

I wanted to create an actual module and require it, but I have not had the time to play with this further. If I accomplish that I will add it here.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any details on your file.js. But I can give you the general idea.

There are two things that you need at minimum to call your package a module:

1. file.js (of course you have it) and
2. package.json

The structure of your file.js should be something like this:

```
//load your dependencies here

var something = require("something");

//module.exports is necessary to export your code, 
//so that you can fetch this code in another file by using require.

module.exports = function() {
    abc: function(){
         //code for abc function
    },
    xyz: function(){
         //code for xyz function
    }
}
```

Now if you put your package on any website, you can access it as:

```
npm install https://ex.com/path/to/js/file.js
```

Now, a copy of your package will be put into node-modules folder.

So, now you can access it as:

```
var x = require('name-of-your-package-in-node-modules');
```

Now, you can also do:

```
var abc = require('name-of-your-package-in-node-modules').abc;
```

or

```
var xyz = require('name-of-your-package-in-node-modules').xyz;
```

Comment: Thank you this is incredibly helpful. However, I would like to have Electron grab the external js file even in the final packaged app. This would be so that I can edit the file on my server and users will see the changes whenever they restart the app, so no need to update! Maybe this isn't even possible, but if you have any idea how to do this let me know :)

Comment: @TMack sorry to say that I don't know much about that type of circumstances. But I think this will be helpful. Let me clear your requirements. You have a package called x on some url. When you update a file in package, and if you restart the electron app, you should have new changes applied. If I am correct, then look at my answer. The simplest thing here will be run npm install x --save everytime before running the app. To automate this process, put npm install x --save in your start script of your package.json file

Comment: @Vishal, that is not what he is asking for. He wants to start an executable and have that executable then pick up the latest script. He cannot run npm update on the clients machine before the starting the executable.

Comment: @PredragStojadinović I am not aware of that. If you have knowledge about that scenario, then please shed some light on that. It will be helpful to me as well some other developers who are facing the same issue.